# MSBuild: Is it possible to specify projects build dependencies in actual project file?

Tags: dll, mfc, msbuild, resources, project

I have a number of different MFC language resource files in an MSBuild system, and I'm trying to build different dlls from each. I have a project file for each in the same directory.

What I'd like to do is specify in the main project file the other project files of the resources to be built.

If I use the

```
  <Import Project="lang_de-DE.xml"/>
```

construction, the main dll will contain the code from the imported projects (according to MSDN MSBuild documentation).

I don't want to use the

```
  <CreateItem Include=.../>
```

construction either, I have them all in one directory.

I have lang_main.xml, lang_en-GB.xml, lang_fi-FI.xml, etc. in on directory, and the .rc files for these in a different directory.

What I need to do is have the lang_main.xml project file build the others first, and then build itself, and have the same number of dlls in the end.
Is it possible to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

What I did was create directories for all languages on the same level with the main language, and put a project file for each of them into the corresponding directory.

Then, I put all the resource files into the main language directory, and in the separate project files I reference their own rc file, by relative path.

Then I used the other language "modules" as dependencies in the main language module, in its project file.